# Error while getting input added into list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am attempting to create a program that asks for the user to enter his/her name and records the input into a list (Was working towards dictionary but seems like I made a boo boo!) but it is returning with "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list". The following is the code.Thanks in advance.

```
namedic = []
while True:
    print ("Please, enter your name:")
    name = input()
    if len(name) > 3:
        print ("Welcome")
    else:
        print ("Ew, your name have less than 4 letters! Gross! Try a new one")
        continue
    namedic = namedic + name
print ("Ah, your name have at least 4 words, good name.")
for name in namedic:
    print (name)
```

Comment: Yeah, because you are trying to concatenate a  string to a list. You can't do that. Have you tried `.append`?

Comment: your loop is infinite, you want break instead of continue

Comment: @Chris_Rands no, the continue is placed right. The OP needs a break inside a conditional _in addition_ to the continue.

Comment: @JakobLovern Ah true

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the suggestions. Append worked for me and adding an if...break ensured finite loop! Hooray!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your erroring line is `namedic = namedic + name`. What you're trying to do is add a list (`namedic`) to a string (`name`). You should do `namedic.append(name)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `+` operator isn't used to append elements to a list, as the error shows. You can use the `append` method for that:

```
namedic.append(name)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#your code should rather be like this;
namedic = []
while True:
    print ("Please, enter your name:")
    name = input()
    if len(name) > 3:
        print ("Welcome")
    else:
        print ("Ew, your name have less than 4 letters! Gross! Try a new one")
        continue
    namedic.append(name)
print ("Ah, your name have at least 4 words, good name.")
for name in namedic:
    print (name)
```